# Truffle returning Big Number

Tags: solidity, tostring, truffle

I'm coding along to a tutorial, and I keep running into this error.
I've tried running toString() in truffle, and tried converting the uint to string in solidity. If someone could point out my error it would be greatly appreciated.

```
   function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 toString){
    require(_owner != address(0),'owner query for non-existent token');
    return _OwnedTokensCount[_owner];

truffle(development)> truffle compile
truffle(development)> truffle migrate
truffle(development)> kryptoBird = await KryptoBirdz.deployed()

// I mint a few tokens 
truffle(development)> kryproBird.mint('https...1')

truffle(development)> kryptoBird.ownerOf(0)
'0x5582aFA98dDD9BB16f33d198911C48fB3B20de60'

truffle(development)> 
kryptoBird.balanceOf('0x5582aFA98dDD9BB16f33d198911C48fB3B20de60')

BN {negative: 0, words: [ 1 <1 empty item>], length:1 , red: null  }
```

This is supposed to return an Integer

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit the question and post the code and console output as text (you can use markdown or the `{}` symbol in the editor to format the code), not as image. It allows answerers to copy-paste parts of it and better troubleshoot the issue. You can find more tips how to ask a good question in the [tour] page.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution you can apply this

`balanceOfAcc = await kryptoBird.balanceOf('0x5582aFA98dDD9BB16f33d198911C48fB3B20de60')` 
`balanceOfAcc.toString()`

Comment: Thank you very much, running this fixed my problem.
I ran 
   ' balanceOf = await 
    kryptoBird.balanceOf('0x5582aFA98dDD9BB16f33d198911C48fB3B20de60')  
    balanceOf.toString() '